# mips number of clock cycles, How to find it

Tags: assembly, mips, clock

*How many clock cycles does these fours instructions take?*

```
#Macro Instructions
li  $t0, 32         #  1 or 2 cycles ?
                    #      
                    # Based on MIPS Assembly Language Programming by Robert Britton :
                    #
                    #                lui $at, Upper 16-bits of value 
                    #                ori Rd, $at, Lower 16-bits of value
                    #                ***OR***
                    #                ori Rt, $0, value
                    #
                    #
                    #  But when I run it on Mars4_3 it showed the assembler 
                    #  converted it to addiu, $8, $0, 0x00000020


div $t2, $t2, $t0   #  41 cycles?          
                    #                bne Rt, $0,
                    #                break $0
                    #                ok: div Rs, Rt
                    #                mflo Rd

#Integer Instruction

lw  $t2, 0($t1)     #  1  cycles?
sw  $t2, 0($t3)     #  1  cycles?
```

---

I used [QtSpim](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/files/) and [Mars4_3](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/) but haven't seen an option to measure clock cycle.I'm wondering if you know, please help me out.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. The specification for the cpu in question (with which I have no specific knowledge) should have the details. What about the book mentioned?

Comment: NO, NOT AT ALL, This is not a Homework question (It is a summer)  The book did a very poor job explaining those.

Comment: It's not summer here ;). Some further investigations indicate that there are a wide variety of chips that use the MIPS architecture - it includes several families of chips. Different chips may take different number of cycles for specific instructions. Wikipedia mentions that the MIPS architecture ranges from the R2000, an 8 - 16mhz chip from 1985, to the MIPS32 proAptiv, running at 1.1ghz (2012).

Comment: Can I also ask, what use is knowing the number of CPU cycles for specific instructions? Rest assured, they are quick! ;)

Comment: @AMADANONInc. Thank You ...   Just Curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can tell you for sure that `lw` and `sw` will certainly not be executed in 1 cycle. In fact, there is no way to say how long it will take for these instructions to execute given that there will be multiple levels of caches for these instructions to go through, each one either hitting or missing. The best you can do for instructions that access memory is to give an average access time.